# SqlKata Values for AsUpdate as column names

Tags: postgresql, sqlkata

I have the following query generated by SqlKata:

```
UPDATE "temp"."dbe01_measures" SET "category2name" = 'category4name'.
```

The expected query is:

```
UPDATE "temp"."dbe01_measures" SET "category2name" = "category4name"
```

I want to use category4name as column name, not as value.

The code for this is:

```
var query = new Query(dimensionDataSource.Object)

var valuesToUpdateForQ1 = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
   {toOptionDataSourceMetadata.NameColumn, fromDimension.DimensionDisplayName}
};

query.AsUpdate(new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>(valuesToUpdateForQ1));

var sqlQueryString1 = new QueryFactory { Compiler = new PostgresCompiler() }.Compiler.Compile(query1).ToString();
```

Comment: What is the expected SQL string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `UnsafeLiteral` to instruct the compiler to consume the value without any processing.

```cs
var q = new Query("Table").AsUpdate(new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"Id", 1},
    {"Value", Expressions.UnsafeLiteral("\"Col\"")}
});
```

This will produce the following:

```sql
UPDATE "Table" SET "Id" = 1, "Value" = "Col"
```